# simple jquery plugin to upload a file via jQuery (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a simple jquery plugin to upload a file without FLASH. For Ruby on Rails.

Single file upload
progress bar indicator and all the bits have been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the Jquery file upload plugin at http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

You can use this gem https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

Cheers,
Abram

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a javascript framework.

File Upload is an HTML element: `<input type="file" />`

You have to process the file upload outside of client side technologies, in RoR for your case.

JavaScript and CSS can help alter the look and feel and the interaction to some extent.

See some plugins here:
http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/